# PostgreSQL copy big data from table to table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have architecture when some data some times is copied to temp table, and then on command, this data with condition must be copied into one of other tables, before this run counts, deletes and updates based on object_id which the same in all tables.
The longest operation is copying - it takes to 10 minutes! on 300 000 rows. 
`insert into t1 (t1_f1, t1_f2, name, value) SELECT DISTINCT ON (object_id) t1_f1, t1_f2, name, value where loading_process_id = 695` - it is for example.

Can I speed up the process? Or this is bad architecture and I have to change it?

Some more - heap table can contains very much data, to copy can be some millions rows. Some fields (which used for counting or filtering) indexed in heap and in other tables.

[image]

And this is plan for not so big data

```
    Insert on main_like  (cost=2993.63..3115.51 rows=6094 width=797) (actual time=6143.194..6143.194 rows=0 loops=1) 
  ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT*"  (cost=2993.63..3115.51 rows=6094 width=797) (actual time=55.995..125.081 rows=6094 loops=1)
        ->  Unique  (cost=2993.63..3024.10 rows=6094 width=796) (actual time=55.909..79.237 rows=6094 loops=1)
              ->  Sort  (cost=2993.63..3008.86 rows=6094 width=796) (actual time=55.904..69.195 rows=6094 loops=1)
                    Sort Key: main_loadingprocessobjects.object_id
                    Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 3321kB
                    ->  Seq Scan on main_loadingprocessobjects  (cost=0.00..465.02 rows=6094 width=796) (actual time=0.578..8.285 rows=6094 loops=1)
                          Filter: (loading_process_id = 695)
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 1428
Planning time: 0.394 ms
Execution time: 6143.631 ms
```

Explain without insert -

```
Unique  (cost=2993.63..3024.10 rows=6094 width=796) (actual time=48.915..52.902 rows=6094 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=2993.63..3008.86 rows=6094 width=796) (actual time=48.911..49.959 rows=6094 loops=1)
        Sort Key: object_id
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 3321kB
        ->  Seq Scan on main_loadingprocessobjects  (cost=0.00..465.02 rows=6094 width=796) (actual time=0.401..5.516 rows=6094 loops=1)
              Filter: (loading_process_id = 695)
              Rows Removed by Filter: 1428
Planning time: 0.214 ms
Execution time: 53.694 ms
```

main_loadingprocessobjects - is heap 
main_like - is t1

Comment: please share an execution plan for `SELECT DISTINCT ON (object_id) t1_f1, t1_f2, name, value where type='ti' and category='added'`

Comment: @VaoTsun if you means explain from pgAdmin, I have added it.

Comment: sorry, no - I meant `explain analyze SELECT DISTINCT ON (object_id) t1_f1, t1_f2, name, value where type='ti' and category='added'`

Comment: done, and I made example query more truthful = )

Comment: can you explain analyze this query ? SELECT DISTINCT ON (object_id) t1_f1, t1_f2, name, value where loading_process_id = 695. without insert statement ?

Comment: @AdrianHartanto yes done, see in post

Comment: Maybe its because many indexes creates with inserting?

Comment: main_loadingprocessobjects is this temporary table? can you change distinct to group by? what about the explain analyze

Comment: @AdrianHartanto no, main_loadingprocessobjects is project's table to fast saving data from different processes without counting and other manipulation, when process ends all this data calculating, effect on other data and then move to target table for long storage and selecting by clients.
Select and count makes fast, but insert - no... maybe it is because small memory or I need to off indexes on inserting time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is several point that you might concern about this issue:

1. **COPY** statement in PostgreSQL is faster than insert into select statement.
2. Create composite index on this following query ex: (type,category).

> SELECT DISTINCT ON (object_id) t1_f1, t1_f2, name, value where
>   type='ti' and category='added'

3. **GROUP BY** Statement is faster than **DISTINCT** statement.
4. Increase **temp_buffer** on postgresql.conf if you consider high usage on temp table.
5. Try **CTE** (Common Table Expresions) instead temp table.

Hope this point my help you in your future development.

Comment: Thanks. hmmm about copy - do I have to copy data from select to file as first, and then copy from file to target table?

Comment: yes, you can do that . or you can combine it with file_fdw that make your file as foreign table. and you can create procedure to execute that process.